# How to avoid actionMessages/actionError generating ul li tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

In my Struts 2 application following tags generating `ul` `li` `span` tags, I have to avoid it. How it could possible? I am also used `theme="simple"`, it doesn't work.

```jsp
<s:actionmessage />
<s:actionerror />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use iterator tag to iterate `actionMessages` or `actionErrors`. The action should extend `ActionSupport`.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="actionMessages">
  <s:property/><br/>
</s:iterator>

<s:iterator value="actionErrors">
  <s:property/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 5):

Iterate them and print each message / error manually, with the HTML you like:

```jsp
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">  
    <div id="messagesDiv" style="border: 10px solid green;">
        <s:iterator value="actionMessages">
            <span class="actionMessage">
                <s:property />
            </span>
        </s:iterator>
    </div>
</s:if>

<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">  
    <div id="errorsDiv" style="border: 10px solid red;">  
        <s:iterator value="actionErrors">  
            <span class="errorMessage">
                <s:property />
            </span>  
        </s:iterator>  
    </div>  
</s:if>
```

The `<span>` (or some other tag) should be kept, in order to semantically separate the messages (to decorate them with a different CSS style tomorrow, for example, which you are unable to do by printing them as simple text).

Otherwise, simply remove the `<span>` and add a `<br>` after the `<s:property/>`

Comment: Not escaping output isn't the best idea, someone can inject a JavaScript in the error message https://struts.apache.org/docs/property.html

Comment: @LukaszLenart I perfectly agree, this answer is quite old, and at that time I used HTML messages, stripping harmful HTML code server-side... it was definitely a mistake not mentioning it in the answer, though (that I've edited now removing the escapes). Thanks for your feedback